# Measuring web page "perception" speed

Tags: performance, frontend, perception

I know of many tools which measure the speed and performance of a web page, however are there any online tools which can measure the site [perceived performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceived_performance) speed?

I'm carrying out various front-end performance improvements and would like to judge how much these change the perceived performance.

Comment: [This other question](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/6196) has a decent answer that might push you in the right direction.

Comment: a service [Highload](http://highload.online) that measure web page loading and compare it with others